# How to control a "Save as" window that opens on a webpage, using Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

So i'm using Selenium with Python to navigate through a website, and to click a button that opens a "Save as" window. How can i control that window ? I need to send a path first where the file should be saved and also to modify the name of the file, then to click "Save".

I think i cannot do this using Selenium because the "Save as" window that opens it is a system dialog window.

What tool or Python script should i use instead to accomplish what i need to do ?
How to control a system dialog window using Python ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a GUI automation package like pyautogui. Explanation in code comments.

```
import pyautogui
import time

# To simulate a Save As dialog. You can remove this since you'll be saving/downloading a file from a link
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 's')
# Wait for the Save As dialog to load. Might need to increase the wait time on slower machines
time.sleep(1)
# File path + name
FILE_NAME = 'C:\\path\\to\\file\\file.ext'
# Type the file path and name is Save AS dialog
pyautogui.typewrite(FILE_NAME)
#Hit Enter to save
pyautogui.hotkey('enter')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked perfectly !!!!!!! Also, can you tell me if there is a way to make the "file.ext" into a parameter that i can change ? How the syntax would be ?

Comment: You can change the variable FILE_NAME = 'C:\\path\\to\\file\\file.ext' to any valid path and file name.

Comment: Can I change the Save as type: Webpage, single file (*.mhtml)?

Comment: What ensures pyautogui acts on the Selenium window and not any other open window?